# CSS prevent multiple transition on div children

Tags: css, css-transitions

```
.product-item :hover{
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.product-item * :hover{
  transition: background-color 0s;
}
```

It seems that applying the transition effect on the parent div affects the children as well. This causes a bubble down effect and looks very ugly. It actually looks like multiply children having their separate transitions.

I've tried to stop the transition on the children but this still doesn't work. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there shouldn't be a space between `.product-item` and `hover`. Then there is no need for the second CSS rule.

```css
.product-item:hover{
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Secondly, you can apply `transition: none` to child elements. Like so:

```css
.product-item:hover .child {
  transition: none;
}
```